# How to convert two columns of dataframe into an orderedDict in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a table named `tableTest` like this:

| startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-15 | 2022-12-18 |
| 2022-12-19 | 2022-12-21 |
| 2022-12-22 | 2022-12-24 |
| 2022-12-26 | 2022-12-27 |
| 2022-12-29 | 2022-12-30 |
| 2022-12-02 | 2022-12-04 |
| 2022-12-06 | 2022-12-07 |
| 2022-12-07 | 2022-12-08 |
| 2022-12-09 | 2022-12-09 |
| 2022-12-13 | 2022-12-14 |

**I need to loop the key-value pairs consisting of startDate and endDate by original order.**

What I did：

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ("2022-12-15", "2022-12-18"),
    ("2022-12-19", "2022-12-21"),
    ("2022-12-22", "2022-12-24"),
    ("2022-12-26", "2022-12-27"),
    ("2022-12-29", "2022-12-30"),
    ("2022-12-02", "2022-12-04"),
    ("2022-12-06", "2022-12-07"),
    ("2022-12-07", "2022-12-08"),
    ("2022-12-13", "2022-12-14"),
    ("2023-01-01", "2023-01-03"),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*('startDate', 'endDate')).toPandas()
dictTest = df.set_index('startDate')['endDate'].to_dict()

print(dictTest)

for k,v in dictTest.items():
    print(f'startDate is {k} and corresponding endDate is {v}.')
```

The above code can indeed convert these two columns to dict, but dict is unordered, so I lost the original order of these two columns.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include your code for tableTest.

Comment: @Zach you should post it as an answer

Comment: @Guoran which python/pandas version do you have? The original order should be preserved for python 3.7+

Comment: @Iohans I refined my question and added code samples.

Comment: @Mozway My Python version is 3.6.9.

Comment: @GuoranYun I'd strongly encourage you to update to a recent version. If you can't Zach's answer seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `into` parameter of `.to_dict` to pass in an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
dictTest = df.set_index('startDate')['endDate'].to_dict(into=OrderedDict)
```

[See the docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use iterrows to iterate in the original order as long as tableTest is a dataframe.

```
for index, row in tableTest.iterrows():
    startDate = row['startDate']
    endDate = row['endDate']
    print(f'startDate is {startDate} and corresponding endDate is {endDate}.')
```